# unable composer install of symfony2

Tags: symfony, composer-php

Composer is working fine (checked the "php composer.phar" command)

However upon trying to install symfony2 by pasting the exakt command from their site, I only get an error like this:

```
Mattias-MacBook-Air:temp acr$ composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition /Users/acr/Documents/www/ "2.3.*"
-bash: composer: command not found
```

-bash: composer: command not found

Do I have to configure my OSX in a certain way for this to work?

If so, is my machine messed up, since that isn't covered in the walkthrough, so I assume other people won't have to?

Comment: Have you tried with "php composer.phar [your params]" directly?

Comment: I only clicked "copy" button on symfony2 website, assumed that is the command to run (not a master of the terminal...). You are right, substituting "composer" in their documentation with "php composer.phar" like you suggest does the trick.

Comment: You should always install composer globally, not locally